# Is there a comprehensive list of the NHibernate event listeners and when they actually fire?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, events

So I am looking for a nice list of NHibernate events that actually describes when they are fired, in a typical scenario (not **just** a list). IE something like

> PreUpdateEventListener - Fires when an
>   object that is already persistent is
>   changing

I currently just rifle through the source and try to figure it out, but it's kinda painful, and I figure that *someone* must have done this already at some point.

Answer (score 4):

Found this [one](http://anandhansubbiah.com/blog/hibernate-events/). This is a java site, but anyway NHibertane is a .net copy of Hibernate :)

Comment: That site really only explains the 'basics' of events. I'm looking for something that describes when each of these events will be called in relation to your typical CRUD operations on an entity.